# Where does Xcode bots place source code after cloning from a repository?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've set up an Xcode build bot system on an OS X CI server machine and it all works successfully.
However I simply cannot find where the bot system is cloning the source code to that it pulls from git. I've searched high and low on the build machine after a bot runs but cannot find any trace of it.

Comment: I don't know off-hand, but you could add a script phase to a target that logs or emails you the contents of the $SOURCE_ROOT variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BotRuns usually create folders inside:

```
/Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/
```

Something like this: [image: Something like this]

Don't forget that you need sudo permissions to handle this folder.

Inside the `Cache` folder you may eventually see a `source` folder. That's where the source code is.

Comment: do you know if it is safe to delete these BotRuns? in hopes of re-creating them. we had to alter Git history, and now commit messages do not appear to work nor be stuffed into TestFlight ditro emails. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Just an update, for **Mojave** and **Xcode 10**, it clone code inside *~/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Bots/*.